# How can I create a list containing all the frequencies of elements in another list ? (in Python code)

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, collections

Suppose there is a list => ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B']

The exact output I am looking for is => [4, 2, 1]

The code I am using:

```
import collections as col
a = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B']
counter=col.Counter(a)

y=[counter.values()]
print(y)
```

The output I am getting is:

```
[dict_values([4, 2, 1])]
```

But I need to someone get it into a list so that I can do further operations.

Can anyone help??

Comment: `list(counter.values())`

Comment: Why don't you just convert it to the list, using `list(counter.values())`?

Comment: Thanks Chris_Rands and Lo L. The issue is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code could be re-written like this:

```
import collections as col
a = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B']
counter = col.Counter(a)
y = list(counter.values())
print(y)
```